# Имя "webpack" не распознано как имя командлета

Tags: javascript, объекты, webpack, babel, модули

Установил Webpack, установка прошла успешно но когда я в терминале ввожу команду webpack для того чтобы создался папка **dist** появляется ошибка

**webpack : Имя "webpack" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- webpack
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webpack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**
  ```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist'
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "My_Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm and webpack tutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Author Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

В чем может быть проблемы?

Comment: В package.json добавь в "scripts" -  "build": "webpack". И запускай через npm run build

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло но не скажешь в чем было поя проблема? что делает это свойство "build": "webpack" и про npm run build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В package.json добавь в

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

И запускай через `npm run build`

Отвечаю на вопрос из коммента. build - это просто название команды, его можно назвать как угодно, главное что он вызывает команду "webpack".
Можно немного расширить и добавить несколько команд:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
},
```

Теперь команда `npm run dev` будет запускать сборку в режиме разработки, а команда `npm run build` в режиме продакшена.

А `npm run ...` это просто команда для запуска соответствующего скрипта

Comment: А в чем разница между режимов разработки и продакшена?

Comment: Ну запустите сборку и посмотрите на итоговый файл

Answer (score 0):

1. установить глобально webpack
   npm install --global webpack webpack-cli
2. изменить политику выполнения скриптов для локальной машины (выполнить команду нужно в PowerShell под Администратором)
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Примечание:

1. установка webpack см. https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation
2. политики выполнения см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2